# Crontab without crontab -e

Tags: cron

I would like to add a crontab schedule by doing this in my server:

```
echo "30 * * * * /home/my/var/dir/to/script /var/etc/etc/etc/" > crontab -e
```

Is there a way to do this without going doing `crontab -e` and then typing in the command?

Comment: or maybee somehting like crontab -e | time commands etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421020/632951 has more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try

```
1)nano /etc/crontab (or any other editor, e.g. emacs)
2)echo "30 * * * * /home/my/var/dir/to/script /var/etc/etc/etc/" > /etc/crontab
3)or put the contents of this into a file, then do "file > /etc/crontab"
```

Comment: but try dont write in /etc/crontab is dangerous!

Answer (score 1):

like root:

```
 echo "30 * * * * /home/my/var/dir/to/script /var/etc/etc/etc/" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the following setup in production on RHEL: 
- a custom software starting sh in init.d , which
- handles cron start , stop , reload
- writes cron tasks into separate tmp file and loads this file with crontab -e

I have been only maintaining it for several months but it works like a charm ...

Answer (score 0):

The proper fix is probably to use a file as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421284/377927, but it is possible to use `tee` to append a line to the crontab by doing e.g.:

```
echo "* * * * * ls" | EDITOR="tee -a" crontab -e
```

`tee -a` will append `stdin` to the file it gets specfied, the `EDITOR` variable tells `crontab` to use `tee -a` as editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the whole crontab in a text file, you can upload a whole crontab to replace the old crontab by doing:

```
cat <crontab_text_file> | crontab -
```

This will wipe out your old crontab.  Using '-' allows you to use standard input into the crontab.