# Use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible to use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?

I know how to list the current crontab jobs of the Apache user:

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
echo $output;
```

But how to add a cron job with PHP? 'crontab -e' would just open a text editor and you will have to manually edit the entries before saving the file.

And how to delete a cron job with PHP? Again you have to manually do this by 'crontab -e'.

With a job string like this:

```
$job = '0 */2 * * * /usr/bin/php5 /home/user1/work.php';
```

How do I add it to the crontab jobs list with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron jobs using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264756/cron-jobs-using-php) and a [couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cron+php)

Comment: *(hint)* the crontab is just a *file*

Comment: @Gordon, thanks. I know everything is a file but are they storing crontab jobs at the same path across different distros? Plus it would need to get the user of Apache, such as www-data, and have the privileges of root?

Comment: I'm not sure if the path changes across distros, but you're doing good to make the path a configurable value in your code and set it at runtime then. As for the user and permissions: every user can have a crontab that runs jobs with the rights assigned to that user, so this is individual for your system setup.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3186471/632951

Comment: Try [yzalis/crontab](https://packagist.org/packages/yzalis/crontab)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**crontab command usage**

```
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [-u user] [ -e | -l | -r ]
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

So,

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

The above can be used for both **create and edit/append** provided the user has the adequate file write permission.

**To delete jobs:**

```
echo exec('crontab -r');
```

Also, take note that apache is running as a particular user and that's usually not root, which means the cron jobs can only be changed for the apache user unless given `crontab -u` privilege to the apache user.

Comment: Wouldn't 'crontab -r' delete all the jobs of the user? Is there any way to delete a specific line of job in the crontabs of the user? Loading, searching and then deleting the found line seems to be the only way.

Comment: You can use pipes instead of writing a temporary file

Comment: Nice solution but `shell_exec('crontab -l')` will only return the last line. I used `exec('crontab -l', $output)`. Then implode the $output array into a string (with \n as the glue).

Comment: @ajreal, I +1ed your comment as a happy DO newcomer myself :) but then I realized that not everybody wants to work as (or hire) a sysadmin in addition to his normal dev. tasks.

Comment: @Rahul if server providers didn't provide shell commands like `system()`, `passthru()` , `shell_exec()` and `exec()`, try using the control panel that comes with the hosting, such as cPanel or Plesk.

Comment: this will keep on appending the same job each time in a file. (checked) is there  a way to remove the matching jobs first then write a new one?

Comment: exec functions are evil, most of the time you do not want them running in your webserver

Comment: Also this solution does not work, as stated above it doesn't append the existing content.

Answer (score 20):

We recently prepared a mini project (PHP>=5.3) to manage the cron files for private and individual tasks. This tool connects and manages the cron files so you can use them, for example per project. Unit Tests available :-)

Sample from command line:

```
bin/cronman --enable /var/www/myproject/.cronfile --user www-data
```

Sample from API:

```
use php\manager\crontab\CrontabManager;

$crontab = new CrontabManager();
$crontab->enableOrUpdate('/tmp/my/crontab.txt');
$crontab->save();
```

Managing individual tasks from API:

```
use php\manager\crontab\CrontabManager;

$crontab = new CrontabManager();
$job = $crontab->newJob();
$job->on('* * * * *');
$job->onMinute('20-30')->doJob("echo foo");
$crontab->add($job);
$job->onMinute('35-40')->doJob("echo bar");
$crontab->add($job);
$crontab->save();
```

github: [php-crontab-manager](https://github.com/MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager)

Comment: Nice. This will certainly come in handy... assuming it actually works :)

Comment: @Pacerier this project seems dead and has some issues. Try [yzalis/crontab](https://packagist.org/packages/yzalis/crontab) which is more active.

Answer (score 12):

**Check a cronjob**

```
function cronjob_exists($command){

    exec('crontab -l', $crontab);

    if( isset($crontab) && 
        is_array($crontab)&&
        in_array($command,$crontab)
    ){

        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

**Append a cronjob**

```
function append_cronjob($command){

    if( is_string($command) && 
        !empty($command) && 
        cronjob_exists($command) === FALSE
    ){
        
        //add job to crontab
        
        exec('crontab -l | { cat; echo "'.$command.'"; } | crontab -');
    }
    
    return cronjob_exists($command);
}
```

**Remove a crontab**

```
exec('crontab -r', $crontab);
```

**Example**

```
exec('crontab -r', $crontab);

append_cronjob('* * * * * curl -s http://localhost/cron/test1.php');

append_cronjob('* * * * * curl -s http://localhost/cron/test2.php');

append_cronjob('* * * * * curl -s http://localhost/cron/test3.php');
```

Comment: function append_cronjob doesn't work for me. I get the output '-' does not exist:

Array ( [0] => '-' does not exist. [1] => usage: crontab file [2] => crontab [ -e | -l | -r ] [3] => -e (edit user's crontab) [4] => -l (list user's crontab) [5] => -r (delete user's crontab) )

Comment: exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n'.$command.'" | crontab -', $output); is it correct. I am getting no crontab for www-data  "-":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Comment: Crontab delimits jobs with line breaks (newlines). Each job occupies one line. Therefore, if crontab sees anything other than an integer in the first column of a line, it throws the “bad minute” error, since the minute argument is the first one crontab encounters. check this out https://www.dougv.com/2006/12/fixing-a-bad-minute-error-message-when-trying-to-use-crontab-with-certain-unix-text-editors/

Comment: thanks... how can i use cron_TZ  using your project ??

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
shell_exec("crontab -l | { cat; echo '*/1    *    *    *    *    command'; } |crontab -");
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried the solution below

```
class Crontab {

// In this class, array instead of string would be the standard input / output format.

// Legacy way to add a job:
// $output = shell_exec('(crontab -l; echo "'.$job.'") | crontab -');

static private function stringToArray($jobs = '') {
    $array = explode("\r\n", trim($jobs)); // trim() gets rid of the last \r\n
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == '') {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

static private function arrayToString($jobs = array()) {
    $string = implode("\r\n", $jobs);
    return $string;
}

static public function getJobs() {
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    return self::stringToArray($output);
}

static public function saveJobs($jobs = array()) {
    $output = shell_exec('echo "'.self::arrayToString($jobs).'" | crontab -');
    return $output; 
}

static public function doesJobExist($job = '') {
    $jobs = self::getJobs();
    if (in_array($job, $jobs)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

static public function addJob($job = '') {
    if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $jobs = self::getJobs();
        $jobs[] = $job;
        return self::saveJobs($jobs);
    }
}

static public function removeJob($job = '') {
    if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
        $jobs = self::getJobs();
        unset($jobs[array_search($job, $jobs)]);
        return self::saveJobs($jobs);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

credits to : [Crontab Class to Add, Edit and Remove Cron Jobs](http://www.kavoir.com/2011/10/php-crontab-class-to-add-and-remove-cron-jobs.html)

Answer (score 4):

You could try overriding the `EDITOR` environment variable with something like `ed` which can take a sequence of edit commands over standard input.

Answer (score 3):

Depends where you store your crontab:

```
shell_exec('echo "'. $job .'" >> crontab');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your file to /etc/cron.d/ in cron format. Add some unique prefix to the filenaname
To list script-specific cron jobs simply work with a list of files with a unique prefix.
Delete the file when you want to disable the job.

Comment: I like this solution better because it avoids manipulating the entire cron file and is easy to remove vs having to add and remove a specific cron task on a huge cron file.

Answer (score 3):

Nice...
Try this to remove an specific cron job (tested).

```
<?php $output = shell_exec('crontab -l'); ?>
<?php $cron_file = "/tmp/crontab.txt"; ?>

<!-- Execute script when form is submitted -->
<?php if(isset($_POST['add_cron'])) { ?>

<!-- Add new cron job -->
<?php if(!empty($_POST['add_cron'])) { ?>
<?php file_put_contents($cron_file, $output.$_POST['add_cron'].PHP_EOL); ?>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Remove cron job -->
<?php if(!empty($_POST['remove_cron'])) { ?>
<?php $remove_cron = str_replace($_POST['remove_cron']."\n", "", $output); ?>
<?php file_put_contents($cron_file, $remove_cron.PHP_EOL); ?>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Remove all cron jobs -->
<?php if(isset($_POST['remove_all_cron'])) { ?>
<?php echo exec("crontab -r"); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo exec("crontab $cron_file"); ?>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Reload page to get updated cron jobs -->
<?php $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php header("Location: $uri"); ?>
<?php exit; ?>
<?php } ?>

<b>Current Cron Jobs:</b><br>
<?php echo nl2br($output); ?>

<h2>Add or Remove Cron Job</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<b>Add New Cron Job:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="add_cron" size="100" placeholder="e.g.: * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/my_cron.php"><br>
<b>Remove Cron Job:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="remove_cron" size="100" placeholder="e.g.: * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/my_cron.php"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="remove_all_cron" value="1"> Remove all cron jobs?<br>
<input type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Remember to add `exit;` after `header('Location: ...');`. Also, this form is actually quite dangerous, as it can add cron job to "destroy" the server.

Comment: Note for beginners: We do not actually wrap every line of PHP in PHP tags. One at the beginning of PHP and optionally one at the end will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the shell_exec command to execute a bash script, passing in the values as parameters. From there, you can manipulate crontabs like you would in any other non-interactive script, and also ensure that you have the correct permissions by using sudo etc.

See this, [Crontab without crontab -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186471/crontab-without-crontab-e), for more info.

Comment: Some people may be in a shared host so this may not work at all.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of crontab you could also use google's app engine [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html). It has a generous free quota, is fast, scalable, modifiable.

Comment: Why not simply use cronjob?

Answer (score -3):

Its simple You can you curl to do so, make sure curl installed on server :

for triggering every minute :
 * * * * * curl --request POST 'https://glassdoor.com/admin/sendBdayNotification'

- - - - *

  minute     hour          day           month           week

Let say you want to send this notification 2:15 PM everyday
**You may change POST/GET based on your API:**

15 14 * * * curl --request POST 'url of ur API'