# How to set a crontab using php?

Tags: php, unix, cron

i need to set a crontab from a php script. i know that it can be set by

> `system("echo '* * * * * echo \"Hello world\"' >> cron.crontab");
>   system("crontab cron.crontab"); //cron.crontab is the file name of the crontab`

"cron.crontab" file is created in root directory, but crontab is not working as expected! when i try the following command, it says that no crontab is set!

> `crontab -l`

i think i am missing something. i am using yii framework. is there an extension to handle cron in yii framework? is there any other way to do it? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate.  The question involves code from the accepted answer there, which doesn't look like it's working.

Comment: The questions are slightly different, but the answer to this one is the last sentence of the accepted answer in the one linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running `crontab -l` as the same user as the web server is running under? Otherwise you won't see its cronjobs.

Answer (score 2):

Apache generally isn't going to be able to muck around with the main crontab.  However, each user has a crontab as well, and it's quite likely that your code above is setting `apache`'s crontab (or the crontab for whatever user your site runs as).

Try `crontab -u apache -l`, or replace `apache` with whatever user your site runs as, and see if the entries you set are there.

Answer (score 0):

You generally have to be root to set the crontab, and it's unlike that php is running as root, in which case you're out of luck.

**Edit:** Not completely out of luck.  See the link in Sebastian's comment above.

Comment: PHP runs as a user on the server...and as a user, it likely has a crontab it could set for itself.  But those jobs would run as the web site/server's user, which may or may not have enough access to get the job done.

Comment: Right you are.  Thanks for the clarification.