# use PHP to schedule cron job

Tags: php, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)

I need to schedule a cron job using PHP:

```
52 15 29 3 2 2011 php -q /var/www/virtualhosts/guy.lt/face2/includes/cron.php
```

How do I do that using `system/shell_exec` or whatever that can be run from the PHP code itself?

Comment: Also if you want to schedule something, there would be the system command `at` which does not involve adapting configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your cron file, or some file for that matter, let's say `cronjobs`, and then running `system("crontab cronjobs")`