# control cron job execution using php script and ajax request

Tags: php, cron

i want a write a php script which can start , stop , enable and disable cron job. I want to create one interactive jquery page which will asynchronously send a request to php file which will stop , start , enable and disable the job

i have searched so many threads but still didn't get a proper way and i have looked following solutions and thread.

[start stop cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548746/how-to-start-stop-a-cronjob-using-php)

i tried to implement the solution provided by J. Bruni but when i try to execute 
`./cron.php` activate i am getting following errors

```
./cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
./cron.php: line 3: =: command not found
./cron.php: line 4: =: command not found
./cron.php: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./cron.php: line 6: `$param    = isset( $argv[1] ) ? $argv[1] : '';'
```

i solved above error by `#!/usr/bin/env php`

**i think my php file get stuck when following line comes**

```
  shell_exec( 'export EDITOR="/home//www/cron.php on"; crontab -e' );
```

and i am getting following error

```
 Window size is too small for nano...crontab: "pico" exited with status 1
```

Comment: Please makes sure the cron user you're editing is not the root cron!!!

Comment: It's very dangerous to give a web based script ability to add/remove stuff from the root cron.  (I'm assuming you're using php as a web script).

Comment: yeah , i know but later on we can implement authentication right ? actually my application demands to have a control over turning on and off cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to execute a php file, on the first line write always write

```
` #!/usr/bin/env php`
```

Then :

1. give the file execution privileges

   `chmod +x file.php`

   Then execute it, as follows

   `./file.php`

Or :

1. execute it using php command

   `php file.php`

Comment: I am getting  this error `Window size is too small for nano...crontab: "pico" exited with status 1'