# How to add a task to crontab using php, like cronjobs in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)

I have a PHP mailing application and I need to have my clients configure a cronjob themselves.

Is there any way to do this with PHP?
Maybe with `shell_exec()` or `exec()`?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. I'm having trouble understanding you