# Run crontab command from php

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, cron

folks, 
 i am very new to PHP, on project that i do now(PHP + Linux), i need to schedule tasks. I know that i can do it using cron. How can i check crontab file from PHP(i have only ftp access to server)? 
I mean i can run 'crontab -l' from terminal(on my local PC). But when i try to do :
echo exec('crontab -l'); - on local PC, it retrn nothing, why it happend ? How can i run command 'crontab -l' from PHP and get output ?
I've tried to use example http://ryanfaerman.com/read/php-crontab-manager, but get compile error.

Comment: Is this your own server? Usually shared servers disable the `exec` function for security reasons.

Comment: If you only have FTP access, I doubt you have access to run shell commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP to create, edit and delete crontab jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)

Comment: right, i can't run crontab there :(

Answer (score 2):

I think crontab will open the user's crontab. Your webserver might be running as root or a different user than you would be.

Try this, but I doubt it will work for security reasons:

```
crontab -u root -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I got nothing from exec('crontab -l'), because i haven't permissions to run crontab and error message is in error stream, so all i need redirect error stream to out stream. 
exec('crontab -l 2>&1') - that is exactly i wanted.