# How to schedule a task on Linux server machine while php interpretator is accessible?

Tags: php, linux, bash

How to schedule a task to linux server system using php script? For example, I need php script to schdule a task for system to run bash script which will backup my files to zip archive? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/ this is an article on creating cron jobs, should get you on your way.

Comment: what about php which will pass a bash file to cron to execute it?

Comment: looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: Why don't you just schedule your bash script to run with cron? Any particular reason to have a PHP script excecute your bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to ssh on that machine you can simply schedule your task using linux's crontab. While logged in, type `crontab -e` which will bring up an editor with the current cron jobs for that user. The syntax is simple, it is composed from 6 parameters, an example line would be :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/php/file
```

the parameters stand for :

```
minute hour day_of_month month day_of_week command_to_run
```

and the command above will run `at_every_minute of_every_hour any_day_of_the_month of_every_month any_day_of_the_week`

If you would like to schedule a task to run at 5:05 am on all mondays of every month it will be something like :

```
5 5 * * 1 /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/php/file
```

A really nice tool is http://corntab.com which will help you schedule your command.

Answer (score 2):

Most comments are in reference to cron jobs but I wonder if you might be able to simply use the [`at` command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

```
`at 12:30 dosomething.sh`
```

If you want a recuring type scheduling solution then cron is the correct path and you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs).