# PHP Exec and at command

Tags: php, cron, shell-exec

I am having trouble executing at command via php.  When I start this job, it runs the 1st time and creates a queue job 1 minute from it finishes the Run Logic.  The queued job runs at specified time but it will not create a new job queue 1 minute after it completes the Run Logic so it dies.

The pseudo logic is
 
`//task_queue.php

if(we_have_tasks){

Run Logic

shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php -f task_queue.php | at now + 1 minutes');

}`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.  I thought if I used the 'at' command I'll be able to schedule jobs without overlapping.

Thanks

Comment: see this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to write `shell_exec('echo "/usr/local/bin/php -f task_queue.php" | at now + 1 minutes');` no? The version you've got re-runs immediately.

Comment: @hobbs I got the "PAM failure: System error" error in response. any comment, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`exec('php /usr/local/bin/php -f task_queue.php | at now + 1 minutes');`