# Set cron job php

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

How can i set a cron job programatically ,

we made a installer for our project and on the installation time i need to set a cron job programatically with PHP.

Please note that the project can be running on LINUX/WINDOWS ,

how can i achieve that ? or is there any better option than CRON JOB.

I am using Codeigniter(Native php based solutions are always welcome , but it will be very helpful if it is through CI)

**THE cron job includes**

1. Check a particular table and remove invalid data
2. Insert values to DB from mailServer
3. Checking the availability of some files.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows doesn't comes with a `cron` command, so I guess you should use `Windows Task Scheduler`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 checkout this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a **nice article** for managing your Cron jobs from PHP

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

this example contain full description of how to write a Cron job from PHP which is manageable from interface with complete source code.

Answer (score 2):

Cron is a job scheduler for linux. It will not work on windows (unless you start getting fancy with Cygwin and etecetera). If you must support it system-wide, across an variety of unknown systems and all in PHP (that cannot schedule things as is) you can resort to any one of these three used solutions:

**Calls from Ground Control**
*(best on resources, concrete times, most elegant solution)*

1. Have your own box running cron and ssh'ing other machines to run commands
2. Have your own box running cron and accesing *"secret url's"* ro run commands
3. Have an external service, like [SetCronJob](https://www.setcronjob.com/) call your *"secret url's"*

**Random Job Runner**
*(the easiest to implement, moderate on resources)*

If you need to do something that will not directly affect the way users behave on your site and it's not time-sensitive (just needs to be done) you can resort to having it run with a statistical probability.

```
// this will run on average once every 100 page views
if(rand(1, 100)==1) runJobQueue();
```

**Worst Case Scenario**
*(harder on resources)*

If your job must be done every so often because it will directly afect the user and it must meet some time schedule you can save query and update a database with the last run timestamp and keep checking on that to see if the job must be re-run

```
// if has passed 1 hour since last update... re-update it
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp` FROM job_times WHERE whatever...")
if(mysql_result($result, 2) >= ( now() - 3600)) {
    runJobQueue()
```

Answer (score 0):

cron job is available to linux, the alternative in windows is schedule task.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569