# mysql alerting via email for value falling below specified amount

Tags: mysql, cron, alert

I am running a simple mysql db that contatins values for temperature sensors in a clients home. I have been looking into different ways to create email alerting if the temp is below or above a preset value.

There are ways that I can accomplish this via a simple php script to be ran off of a cron job from what i have gathered but the problem with them is it needs to be put 'on hold' for a certain amount of time that way once a client gets an alert they wont keep getting that alert every five minutes when the cron runs.

Also as a future question of this project, is there a way to have cron jobs created from values that users store in the sql db? That way the users can have customized alerting?

Sorry if it didn't come out clear, I will be right next to the computer all day to answer questions on this regard if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem, create an `alerts` table that keeps track of when the last alert was. Depending on your platform, it may be possible for [PHP to schedule cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs). You could save the user settings in a table and have PHP create/update/delete the cron jobs.

Comment: So the alerting table would simply have the last time an alert was triggerd for that account and a value say 1.

Then have a script that says 

if timestamp > xamount of time then run this alerting query again?

Comment: You don't need a value; you just need a stamp (`datetime`) of the last alert.

Comment: Holy wow that was quick. I just hit the enter key on accident when trying to shift enter. But alright i see how you could simply do that and it solves a good bit of my problem with this. I will look into the custom php cron jobs later. The end result will be user customized alerting for a simple sql db and I think I can do that with what you have told me.