# Mysql query to update status on condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update

**Databse table**-

```
     id        created_date             timer     status 
      1    2013-02-25 16:40:45           1        Y  
      2    2013-02-25 16:40:45           2        Y  
      3    2013-02-25 16:40:45           0        Y
```

This is my database table.

`created_date` field is `datetime` and `timer` is `varchar` value (`integer value`)

**what I want is to `set status N` for every day at `12:00 AM`  and when timer value is not `0` then set `status=N` by adding `timer+created_date` , all status change to `N` at `12:00 AM` weather timer set or not**.

Comment: @ChetterHummin i will make a query to update status at 12:00 AM but i don'y get how to deal with timer and update according to timer value . give me a clue . I am new in programing.

Comment: what you have tried ? can you share some code ?

Comment: Update timer set status = 'N' where created_date = '12:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must take advantage of `cronjob`.

some helpful links are :

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/168

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: I want to make a query not running a crone .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Update tableName
set status = 'N'
where time <> 0 and time(created_date) = '12:00:00'
```

Then to update the date with the time value assuming its in seconds you do this

```
Update tableName
set created_date= AddTime(created_date, timer)
where status = 'N'
```

Comment: how to add timer value in that to set status = 'N'

Comment: You want to add timer+created_date to which column? created_date  or to timer ? and timer is in seconds or minutes ?

Comment: timer is in hours . want to update status after   timer+created_date time is completed. and all status to N at 12:00 AM it does't depend on timer value.