# Need to edit root crontab jobs from webinterface??

Tags: php, apache, cron

I want to edit the `crontab` of `root` from the web interface. I have `Apache` and `PHP` installed on my `Ubuntu`. If there is any permissions required please also mention that.

I want to edit the crontab of root. I have some jobs running in that crontab. One of my projects wants me to change the running jobs Time from web interface.

So please tell me how can I access the crontab of root and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

permission problems: solve those by allowing `www-data` to run the appropriate commands via `sudo`.

run `crontab -u root -l` to get the current crontab, edit it with php string manipulation code of your liking and intall it with `crontab -u root $FILE`. i recommend to place markers in the file to make it easier to find the correct places to edit like so:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# ...
# m  h  dom mon dow   command
  0 14   27   *   *   backupmails-monthly.sh
  0 14    *   *   5   backupmails-weekly.sh
# MARKER_EDIT_HERE_START
  0 14   27   *   *   job_to_edit.sh
# MARKER_EDIT_HERE_END
```

a better solution if jobs run regularly: don't put them in the crontab but in `/etc/cron/cron.{hourly,daily}`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the console, you should install webmin for web management interface of the server

http://www.webmin.com/

Comment: Yes but i am building a product that will be accessed by Admins ,and its just for particular purpose.From webmin i can do so many things.But i will surely take look @user2068102.

Comment: I may have figured out your problem, but unfortunately I have ever dealt with. You could see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs or wait for the response of someone.

Answer (score 0):

These days there are tools like

- [chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) (depends on apache, has a [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/chronos/))
- [luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) from spotify
- [minicron](https://github.com/jamesrwhite/minicron)
- More options found at the github topic: [cron](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=topic%3Acron+&type=)