# Sending a message to an email at a specific time

Tags: php, html

HELP! For this specific HTML code, I would want to send a message to an email address at a specific date and time. The date is 1/1/2013 and the time is 2:12am. I would like to input a message and send that message to an email at the given date and time. How would I do this according to the code below? Either using php or html?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Lab </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login">
            <form method="post" action"#">
                <p>
                    E-mail
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Message
                    <br>
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="message"> </textarea>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Date: Month
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="01"> 1 </option>
                    </select>

                    Day
                    <select name="day">
                        <option value="01"> 1 </option>

                    </select>

                    Year
                    <select name="year">
                        <option value="2013"> 2013 </option>
                    </select>

                    Hour
                    <select name="hour">
                        <option value="02"> 02 </option>
                    </select>

                    Minute
                    <select name="minute">

                        <option value="12"> 12 </option>

                    </select>
                </p>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cant send an email from HTML, you need to use PHP or another server sided lanaguage

Comment: this is as bad a question as the one you just deleted

Comment: Server sided scripting and a little magical gem called Cronjobs/Scheduled task.

Comment: HTML is a markup language. What you're asking makes as much sense as trying to ask how to make chocolate cake with nothing but vanilla icing.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to use PHP, with some mysqli and an cronjob.

First you save the "message" ( from the HTML form ) in the database. Make sure you save the uid of that entry in PHP

Second you create an cronjob with PHP. more about that [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421284/1846175). Make the cron job so that it will be executed when needed and that the UID is in the url to ( as an [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable )

third, you need an page where the cron job is heading to. Make sure that an [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable with the UID is passed to the page.

Get the info out of the DB and mail the message.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you need to do is format the email, set the action value to some php page (for example process.php

You can access the variables from the $_POST array, I would then put it into a database with fields for: to,message,subject,and the time that its supposed to go out (format the date into a timestamp using the date() function
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp - this is a good tutorial for mysql

Then create a cron job from your control panel that runs a php script with the following sudo code every minute(if you really want to get ocd about it you can write a script that creates cron jobs everytime a new email is added)

1.Connect to database

2.Find anything with a timestamp before the current time (calculated with the time() function)

3.Send out the email with the php email function (or a library )

1. Delete the row from the database

Comment: 1. The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated. 2. [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/).