# stoping crons from web interface

Tags: php, linux, shell, php-5.4

Using cron say i am running crons as :

```
php symfony cron:cronName TEST 144
php symfony cron:cronName REAL 144
php symfony cron:cronName REAL 1441
php symfony cron:cronName TEST 1441
```

I am required to provide an web interface where these crons can be stopped.

For example if input 45 is given from web interface 1st and 2nd crons  should be stopped but not third and fourth.

Please help

Comment: cronjobs is an ordinary text file, which you can override with your custom test > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: No No ....... i am asking these crons are running and i need to stop them using some commands ?

Comment: I have a type in my comment above, test=text. Yes, and I am answering, that you can make web interface where you can, add/remove/edit cronjobs, and when finished, you will need to save your edits to the cronjobs file.

Comment: i need linux command to kill them in a pattern