# Replace contents of MySQL table with contents of csv file on a remote server

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, csv

I'm a newbie here trying to import some data into my wordpress database (MySQL) and I wonder if any of you SQL experts out there can help?

Database type: MySQL

Table name: `wp_loans`

I would like to completely replace the data in table `wp_loans` with the contents of file `xyz.csv` located on a remote server, for example `https://www.mystagingserver.com/xyz.csv`

All existing data in the table should be replaced with the contents of the CSV file.

The 1st row of the CSV file is the table headings so can be ignored.

I'd also like to automate the script to run daily at say 01:00 in the morning if possible.

**UPDATE**

Here is the SQL I'm using to try and replace the table contents:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'https://www.mystagingserver.com/xyz.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE wp_loans

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'

IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: can you provide the tablestructure and example input? For the second part of your question, have a look at creating cronjobs in php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: i've added the sql input to the original question and will take a look at the cron job post. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a cron job to automate the process, and probably use BCP (bulk copy) to insert the data into a table... But seeing as you are using MySQL, instead of BCP, try load data in file - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/

Comment: I have a permissions issue now but think that should do it. Thank you