# Cron Job in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I want to create and use cron job . But i want it to be done by my script in codeigniter.
So is it possible to add a cronjob for a perticualr time when my conrtoller function is completed ?

If so please help...
Thank you

Comment: Are you want to run it by which server windows/linux?

Comment: "No my server is linux and i want to create cronjob dynamically thorugh script..."

Comment: Chirag, cronjobs are unix-like systems only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can!

You can execute any controller/action in codeigniter on command line this way:

> php index.php controller_name action_name

So you can point a cron job on this particular route and execute anything that don't depends on browser (like sessions/cookies) into your job.

More info: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Comment: Yes, you can since the user that executes de application (it would depend of your webserver's configuration) has the right permission to create a cron that'll exec the script.

Comment: i am trying also the same thing...but through crontab -e command i am not able to create new cron job

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs/

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't working for me ... that format takes it to the index page but not to the controller and method. Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl in cron jobs to execute or run the codeigniter in cron jobs

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl https://www.domain.com/controller/function
```