# Ajax call facing an awkward situation

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Please bare me for long question...

I have to add one database record to one master table let say `test` table. After adding record to this table I want its `last inserted id` and then want to add approximate 1000 entries into transaction table (also sending EMAILS to these 1000 records) let say `test_transaction` table.

But this second operation, adding record into transaction table, takes more second to add records to database. I am using customer MVC and my code looks like...

```
public function addtotest()
{
    $strSql = "INSERT INTO test ...";
    $intId = $this->db->execute($strSql);

    foreach($arrTransaction $transact)
    {
        $strSql = "INSERT INTO test_transaction ...";
        $this->db->execute($strSql);
    }

    echo $intId;
}
```

So I want to put `test_transaction` table's entries into another `action` like below

```
public function testtrancation()
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['id']; //It's understood that I am doing proper validation here
    foreach($arrTransaction $transact)
    {
        $strSql = "INSERT INTO test_transaction ...";
        $this->db->execute($strSql);
    }
}
```

So main question, I am calling `addtotest` action from an `AJAX` and when it will give `id` in response I want to call another `AJAX` which will add approximate `1000` records to database.

BUT I do not want to disturb users' experience by letting them to wait for another few minutes for `1000` records.

1. So I am reloading page after record has been added by `addtotest` `AJAX' call.
2. Calling another `AJAX` call in `success` of `addtotest`.
3. And after calling `testtransaction` `AJAX` call, I am reloading my page.

   ```
   $.ajax(
   {
       url: SERVER_PATH + 'addtotest',
       type: 'post',
       async: true,
       data: { required_data: required_date },
       success:function(data)
       {
           alert('Record added successfully.');

           //I DO NOT WANT USERS TO WAIT FOR THIS AJAX CALL
           $.ajax(
           {
               url: SERVER_PATH + 'testtransaction',
               type: 'post',
               async: true,
               data: { intId: data.id },
               success:function(data)
               {
               //DO NOTHING
           },
           });
           //I DO NOT WANT USERS TO WAIT FOR THIS AJAX CALL

           location.reload();
       },
   });
   ```

But as page get reloaded my `AJAX` call is also get vanished without completing `AJAX` request.

So could be done in this case? I you want more details then please let me know.

I do not want users to wait for another `1000` entries (plus sending EMAILS to these 1000 records) being made into database.

Comment: @NeilA, thank you very much for improving question.

Comment: Just glad to help

Comment: I've never used them but what about using the Ajax call to [start a cronjob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs)?

Comment: @Terminus, I cannot create cronjob for this task as my server is already executing lots of cronjobs for certain time.

Comment: You can publish the event on redis when you insert the data on test table and listen for that even using node js.

Comment: try using the server side event-handler mechanism to insert 1000 records after inserting into the main table. It would be helpful

Comment: Why would you involve the client in your 2nd thousand inserts? Why involve PHP even? If the thousand inserts are 100% dependent on the last insert ID then you can probably do the whole thing in a MySQL Stored Procedure!

Answer (score 3):

Just Create a Database Trigger then.
So When Record Gets inserted in First Table 
it inserts into transaction table or SO.

Exampl -

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trg_Table1_INSERT
 ON dbo.Table1 AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(SerialNo, Name)
  SELECT SerialNo, Name
  FROM Inserted

   INSERT INTO dbo.Table3(SomeOtherCol)
  SELECT SomeOtherCol
  FROM Inserted
END
```

Comment: I think we cant get the request information in the triggers. Am I right ?

Comment: We Dont Need Request information I guess. We only need id of Insert.See Updated.

Comment: Adding `trigger` would be a good idea that I do not need to wait for it on Front-End.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple!

After single insert you can call to separate background process:

```
public function addtotest()
{
    $strSql = "INSERT INTO test ...";
    $intId = $this->db->execute($strSql);
    exec('php /your/php/cli/script.php param1 param2 paramN 1>> /dev/null 2>> /dev/null &');
    echo $intId;
}
```

With "&" process starts in the background, so you can continue and do not have to wait until the script is finished.

Or you can add this job into "deferred tasks" and run this tasks with cron.

Comment: will my MVC url work with `exec`? Like I have url `SERVER_PATH . "controller/addtotest/id/1`

Comment: Dont known about your framework. But many frameworks support CLI mode. Like: /usr/bin/php /path/do/cli-index.php -q controller/addtest/id/1

Comment: @NullPointer or... you can call to your site with curl or wget like: exec('wget http://domain.tld/controller/addtotest/id/1 1>> /dev/null 2>> /dev/null &'), but this is not safe. Because, maybe this action require auth/login.

Comment: yeah but I think using cURL in same site is advisable? Can't I call using anything from client side and rest of the job is done automatically without keep users in wait?

Comment: @NullPointer, with & process starts in the background, so you can continue and do not have to wait until the script is finished.

Comment: Ok. Then let me check and I will back to you with the result. Thank you so much :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AJAX for that. You need CRONJOB with basic pagination.

In one php file extract ID and after that list sequence per 500 request for each sequence. And with header() redirect on the next 500 until you reach end. That will not affect on user experience and ypu will have good performances.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert all the rows with one sql query.

```
INSERT INTO test_transaction (col1, col2)
VALUES (value11, value12),
(value21, value22),
(value31, value32),
...
(value10001, value10002);
```