# Adjusting cron tasks over a PHP web interface?

Tags: php, cron, raspberry-pi

Would there be any way to adjust cron tasks over a PHP web interface? I was thinking I could just use `shell_exec()` commands but it runs into a snag when `crontab -e` launches a text editor. If cron isn't the thing to use for this job, then I will gladly take other suggestions compatible with Raspberry Pi. My end goal is just to be able to adjust the time that a program is run over a webpage.

Comment: I think most web-edited crons insert the specific information into a database, then use an actual cron to run a script that checks those entries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs

Comment: Mine does `exec('echo '.escapeshellarg($newcrontab).' | crontab - 2>&1',$ret,$code);`

Comment: Thank you all very much. @P.Danielski that question helps a lot! Sorry for asking a previously asked question.