# crontab with ed by commands on stream, results in "no modification made"

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ed

I am trying to append a line to my crontab file. I know there are other ways to work around this problem, but still want to know what caused it. The command is run on raspberry pi 3 B+, raspbian lite is installed, with GNU ed 1.15, cron 3.0pl1-134+deb10u1.

The command that I'm stuck on is this:

```
$ echo -e 'a\n#asdf\n.\nwQ' | EDITOR=ed crontab -e
902
909
No modification made
```

I'm expecting it to add line `#asdf` at the end of my crontab file, but it doesn't.

Setting `EDITOR='tee -a'` as suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30123606/8842387 does not solve the problem. So I guess it is the problem with cron.

Strangely enough, when I give ed commands from the keyboard directly, rather than streaming it, it just works. Maybe subshell creation caused the problem?

Here I'm attaching a few of the last lines from `strace` result.

```
$ echo -e 'a\n#asdf\n.\nwQ' | EDITOR=ed strace crontab -e
execve("/usr/bin/crontab", ["crontab", "-e"], 0x7ee54c14 /* 29 vars */) = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 659
_llseek(3, -393, [266], SEEK_CUR)       = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 393
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 18579
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
send(3, "<78>Nov 20 15:31:25 crontab[1857"..., 56, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 56
openat(AT_FDCWD, "crontabs/pi", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1433, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1433, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x76f50000
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "crontabs/pi/: fdopen: Permission"..., 39crontabs/pi/: fdopen: Permission denied) = 39
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "crontabs/pi", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)` looks a bit suspicious, but not sure why it opens the file read-only.

EDIT:
As suggested by @tink, I ran `EDITOR=ed strace crontab -e` to see what `strace` gives on an interactive session. The result was almost same (only varying on pid and fd numbers).

I noticed that running `echo "..." | EDITOR=ed crontab -e` exited with message `No modification made` but with `strace` the process halts without any messages. (`EDITOR=ed strace crontab -e 2>&1 | grep "No mod"` prints nothing). Guess the strace triggers different errors.

Comment: Interesting ... could you please also paste what the "interactive" sessions' strace looks like?

Comment: Not that I'm convinced that this is `programming` - personally I think this is a question better suited for [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: `crontab` is set-gid, but that's disabled when you run it from `strace`. That's why it gets "Permission denied" in the trace. It's not showing what's happening when you run it normally.

Comment: I suggest you use `printf` instead of `echo -e`. It's more portable.

Comment: I think `crontab` uses `$VISUAL` before `$EDITOR` -- do you have a VISUAL env var?

Comment: @tink Thanks for your comment! I added more info on the question. By the way, is there a way to move the question to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Barmar I see, that's why it gave me the same error while running interactively. Any other way to inspect what is going on?` For other people reading this, I found this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530298) explaining why `printf` is more portable. ;)

Comment: I know it's dangerous, but maybe if you did this as root it wouldn't mind that it can't change groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**; `(sleep 1; echo -e 'a\n#asdf\n.\nwQ') | EDITOR=ed crontab -e` works!

The problem was on `crontab`.

When I invoke `crontab -e` it creates a temporary copy of the user cron table in `/tmp` directory.
Then opens the temporary file with an editor specified by `$EDITOR`.
After the editing is done, `crontab` check if the file modification date have changed since its creation.
This is implemented in the [patch](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blob/master/debian/patches/fixes/Allow-editors-with-tmpfiles.patch#L123) that enables editing cron table via temporary file.

In my case, `ed` getting its command from `stdin` finished the editing too fast so that even a single digit of the modification timestamp of the temporary file had not been changed.
As `crontab` considered no human can make edition that fast, it assumes no modification made and discards it.

To bypass this behavior, I added `sleep 1` before the release of the command.
This will hold `ed` to wait for its command from `stdin` after `crontab` created tempfile, which effectively lets the modification timestamp different.

Comment: Why not simply `(crontab -l; echo new stuff) | crontab -` instead?

Comment: @tripleee That's another way to go! Simple and nice solution. I had been using a similar - but dirtier - workaround till I locate the problem. Besides, my question was on curiosity, "why doesn't this work while seems obvious?" rather than "how to do this?".

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my VISUAL comment, these worked for me:

```sh
( unset VISUAL; printf '%s\n' a '#abcd' . wq | EDITOR=ed crontab -e )
```

```sh
printf '%s\n' a '#abcd' . wq | VISUAL=ed crontab -e
```

In my environment, both VISUAL and EDITOR are set to "vim"

Or, more roundabout, but don't need to monkey with env vars. This one also allows you to do it silently:

```sh
crontab <(printf '%s\n' a '#asdf' . '%p' | ed -s <(crontab -l))
```

---

I was doing the above on a Mac. On Linux, I can reproduce your observations, but can't explain them.

A small tweak to the last command works:

```sh
printf '%s\n' a '#asdf' . '%p' Q | ed -s <(crontab -l) | crontab -
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm afraid to say that neither of the above two lines worked for me and the last one gives `/dev/fd/63: Not a regular file.` Maybe some system configuration be different?